# Ошибка авторизации ВК - vk_api.exceptions.LoginRequired: Login is required to auth

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Код:

```
C:\bot vk>Runner.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\bot vk\Runner.py", line 2, in <module>
    from Bot import Main
  File "C:\bot vk\Bot.py", line 3, in <module>
    from Utils import Engine as UEngine
  File "C:\bot vk\Utils\Engine.py", line 6, in <module>
    from VK import VK
  File "C:\bot vk\VK.py", line 10, in <module>
    vk.auth ()
  File "C:\Users\fanta\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\vk_api\vk_api.py", line 169, in auth
    raise LoginRequired('Login is required to auth')
vk_api.exceptions.LoginRequired: Login is required to auth
```

Comment: Сам код где потерялся? :)

Comment: Нет. Вопрос решен вводом реальных данных от аккаунта и отключением 2FA.